# How to override jquery plugin options with html5 data-attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

What I want to do is to set options into plugin like you normally would, but to also override those options with html5 data-attributes.

[Here I have exactly that (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/HvbdL/), but there's a slight problem with that.

JSFiddle Code:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        test: function(options) {

            var defaults = {
                background: null,
                height: null
            };

            var options = $.extend( defaults, options);

            return this.each(function() {
                  var o = options;
                  var obj = $(this);
                  var objD = obj.data();


                    // background
                    if ( !objD.background) {
                        var cBG = o.background;
                    }
                    else {
                        var cBG = objD.background;
                    }

                    // Opacity
                    if ( !objD.height) {
                        var cH = o.height;
                    }
                    else {
                        var cH = objD.height;
                    }

                    obj.css({
                        background: cBG,
                        height: cH  
                    });

            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.test').test({

        background: 'red',
        height: 400

    });
});
```

The method that I'm using in the jsfiddle bloats the code so much, even with just 2 different options that are also using data.

**Question is:** How could I achieve same end result with less code, to determine wether or not data should be used?

---

---

Here is the part of the code from the jsfiddle, that determines wether or not to use data.

```
// objD is obj.data();

// background
if ( !objD.background) {
    var cBG = o.background;
}
else {
    var cBG = objD.background;
}

// Opacity
if ( !objD.height) {
    var cH = o.height;
}
else {
    var cH = objD.height;
}

obj.css({
    background: cBG,
    height: cH  
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a feeling that there might be a better solution, but I wasn't able to get it working, until now.

---

Of course I am no expert, but this seems to work and shortens the code even more, since it works the same way the plugin options normally do, it just adds the `data-attribute` in there.

1. `Default` - Initially use `default` options.
2. `Custom` - If set, use custom `options` to override `default`s.
3. `Data` - If set, use `data` to override both.

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/HvbdL/5/

```
o = $.extend(true, {}, options, $(this).data() );
```

---

---

[Here's another jsfiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/TP9vx/)

This one toggles the width of each box on click. The middle box has a data-attribute with bigger width value than the other divs.

As an extra example, [here's the same thing](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/TP9vx/1/) with 1 more option added in to the mix.

Answer (score 2):

Well, one common trick is the double-pipe "or" operator in your assignment. If the first value is true, the second one is ignored, since only one true statement is enough to make the entire expression true:

```
var cBG = objD.background || o.background;
var cH = objD.height || o.height;
```

In fact, if you don't need those variables anywhere else, just add the results into the last statement:

```
obj.css({
    background: (objD.background || o.background),
    height: (objD.height || o.height)
});
```

[Your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HvbdL/2/)

[Simplified example](http://jsfiddle.net/LwFQ3/)

Now if `objD.background` is any "falsey" value (such as null, undefined, false, zero, or the empty string), then `o.background` will automatically be used. If for some reason you don't want that, you should use the ternary operator with an appropriate test instead:

```
obj.css({
    background: (objD.background!=undefined) ? objD.background : o.background,
    height: (objD.height!=undefined) ? objD.height : o.height
});
```

Comment: Simpler than what I did, but I'm a bit concerned how if I would set value `0` into `data-` it seems to jump straight to `options`. Same thing happens if data has `false`, it jumps straight to `options`. Which means that I can't override with those values.

Comment: if you set `objD.background` to zero, then `!objD.background` would have evaluated as true and you'd get the same result. But I'll update my answer to address that.

Comment: I see.. I used to use  `if ( objD.cBG != null ){ options } else { data }` but thought that using `!` was a bit shorter, so I jumped to that without thinking about it much :)

Comment: It's worth testing for different "falsey" values, too. For instance, in JavaScript, it seems `null==undefined` is true, but `null===undefined` is not. Be careful what you let through.

Comment: In my prior comment/if statement I meant to put `data` before `options` ..I seem to have gotten confused. As far as you answer goes, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be using the jQuery [HTML5data plugin](https://github.com/markdalgleish/jquery-html5data) from Mark Dalgleish. The pro side of this plugin is namespacing so your config will never clash with the config of some other plugin.